# Generate a Pie Chart in Tableau Showing What % of Source Requirements have Derived Requirements

Tags: tableau-api

I am trying to generate a pie chart in Tableau that shows the percentage of Source Requirements that have a corresponding Derived Requirement. I would also like to show what percentage of Source Requirements have test cases under every single one of their derived requirements. The output from the database I am working with exports tracing information as a unique line item for each derived requirement at the lowest tier of the database. What this means is that the Source Requirement is duplicated for every single derived test case, as shown in the table:

[image: Requirement Trace View Export]
Likewise, each derived requirement is duplicated for every test case as well. As a result, some source requirements have hundreds of duplicates.

Comment: So, with that dataset, what kind of result do you want to get?

Comment: I am trying to generate an interactive chart that can show what % of Source Requirements have at least 1 associated Derived Requirement. Also, I would like to show what % of source requirements have at least 1 test case for all derived requirements.